# TKInter frame losing grid layout when insert scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create an app with a frame with two frames inside, but I want one of then to be wider than the other... I found a way to do it using grid, but when I add a scrollbar on one of the frames it readjusts the grid and both frames get the same size.

**Here is the code working without the scrollbar:**

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    ctk.set_appearance_mode('system')
    ctk.set_default_color_theme('blue')

    self.__root = ctk.CTk() if master is None else ctk.CTkToplevel(master)
    self.__root. Configure(height=1500, width=944)
    self.__root.minsize(1500, 944)

    self.__main_container = ctk.CTkFrame(self.__root)

    self.__image_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.__main_container)
    self.__image_frame.configure(height=800, width=1000)

    self.__image_canvas = ctk.CTkCanvas(self.__image_frame)
    self.__image_canvas.configure(confine="true", cursor="crosshair")
    self.__image_canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.__image_canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.__start_drawing)
    self.__image_canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.__end_drawing)
    self.__image_canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.__draw_rectangle)

    self.__image_frame.grid(column=0, padx=10, pady=20, row=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.__image_frame.grid_propagate(0)
    self.__image_frame.grid_anchor("center")
    self.__image_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.__image_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.__boxes_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.__main_container)
    self.__boxes_frame.configure(height=800, width=400)
    self.__boxes_frame.grid(column=1, padx=10, pady=20, row=0, sticky="ns")

    self.__main_container.grid(column=0, padx=20, pady=40, row=0, sticky="ns")
    self.__main_container.grid_anchor("center")
    self.__main_container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.__root.grid_anchor("center")
    self.__root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.mainwindow = self.__root
```

[image: working code generates this frames]

**And this is the code when I add the scrollbar and messes the grid**

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    ctk.set_appearance_mode('system')
    ctk.set_default_color_theme('blue')

    self.__root = ctk.CTk() if master is None else ctk.CTkToplevel(master)
    self.__root. Configure(height=1500, width=944)
    self.__root.minsize(1500, 944)

    self.__main_container = ctk.CTkFrame(self.__root)

    self.__image_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.__main_container)
    self.__image_frame.configure(height=800, width=1000)

    self.__image_canvas = ctk.CTkCanvas(self.__image_frame)
    self.__image_canvas.configure(confine="true", cursor="crosshair")
    self.__image_canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.__image_canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.__start_drawing)
    self.__image_canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.__end_drawing)
    self.__image_canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.__draw_rectangle)

    #------ adding the scrollbar -----
    self.__image_frame_vertical_scrollbar = ctk.CTkScrollbar(self.__image_frame, orientation="vertical")
    self.__image_frame_vertical_scrollbar.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="ns")
    self.__image_frame_vertical_scrollbar.configure(command=self.__image_canvas.yview)
    self.__image_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.__image_frame_vertical_scrollbar.set)
    #---------------------------------

    self.__image_frame.grid(column=0, padx=10, pady=20, row=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.__image_frame.grid_propagate(0)
    self.__image_frame.grid_anchor("center")
    self.__image_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.__image_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.__boxes_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.__main_container)
    self.__boxes_frame.configure(height=800, width=400)
    self.__boxes_frame.grid(column=1, padx=10, pady=20, row=0, sticky="ns")

    self.__main_container.grid(column=0, padx=20, pady=40, row=0, sticky="ns")
    self.__main_container.grid_anchor("center")
    self.__main_container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.__root.grid_anchor("center")
    self.__root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.mainwindow = self.__root
```

[image]

What is wrong with the grid definition that is messing things up? How can I set the __image_frame grid to it fills the __main_container keeping the desired dimensions?

Comment: Forgot to say... I'm using Python 3.10.8 and the library customtkinter

Comment: I'm using [Pygubu Designer](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu-designer) and it expands the `__image_frame` when previewing it on the designer UI

Comment: Ok... It seems to be a customtkinter issue, because when I change the code to use default tkinter it works fine...Anyway, if anyone know how to fix it or suggest me a better library to make tkinter prettier, it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the size of the canvas explicitly

```
self.__image_canvas = ctk.CTkCanvas(self.__image_frame, width=900)
```